# JUnit testing HTTP Call through a mock proxy?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, proxy

I am looking for a simple way to JUnit/test my network calls such as HTTP *without* changing the calling address at all.

My class do a very simple job:

```
public String callHttp (method, proxy infos, ..)
{    
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HostConfiguration config = client.getHostConfiguration();
    config.setProxy("myproxy", 8080);
    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("myuser","mypwd");
    AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope("myproxy", 8080,AuthScope.ANY_REALM);
    client.getState().setProxyCredentials(authScope,credentials);
    int returnHttpCode = client.executeMethod(new GetMethod("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=httpclient&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq="));
}
```

(Note that in real code, proxy infos are parameters)

Was thinking about to mock the proxy that will return mock responses.

I found several solutions ([Testing methods that make http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997643/testing-methods-that-make-http-requests) ) but all require to change the call address :(
Is there a way to only mock the proxy (JUnit/Maven) and returning whatever I want?

Comment: Do you absolutely need a proxy? Why not mock the `HttpClient` methods instead? Since this class is not `final` you can do that...

Comment: Yes the final code alway use a proxy (entreprise network). I've tried this solution http://blog.newsplore.com/2010/02/09/unit-testing-with-httpclient but I am looking for a solution based on a mocked proxy. May be SOAPUI can do the job ?

Comment: I think more code is needed here; in particular the code where you set the proxy to use etc

Comment: I just found LittleProxy, which looks like it might be perfect.  It's a lightweight Java proxy service that you can build into your project.  You can create custom handlers, which I believe could serve to redirect requests to whatever source you want to implement.  https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy

Comment: More info on using LittleProxy here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/littleproxy/-9uHetgop14

Comment: LittleProxy is no longer maintained